# Property of primes / property of other sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Conjecture

> If we have two consecutive prime numbers $p_{n}$ and $p_{n+1}$, and another arbitrary prime number $p_a$ such that $p_{n} < p_{n+1} < p^2_{a}$,
>   then it follows that $p_{n+1} - p_{n} < p_{a} $.

Are there any known counter examples or reasons for this being true?

What is the name of this property or a similar one with respect to general sequences, (not necessarily the sequence of primes)?

Comment: $p_n=113$, $p_{n+1}=127$, $p_a=13$ is a counterexample and my gut feeling tells me there wouldn't be any others. The Wikipedia entry on [prime gaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Conjectures_about_gaps_between_primes) provides quite a few conjectures, some of which are stronger than this one.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Opperman's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Conjectures_about_gaps_between_primes) on prime gaps, and related results? See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/541727/242)

Comment: No not really, I tend to "explore" without following reference material, but I probably should. So thanks for giving me a target topic to get up to grasp with. Thanks for the counter example Peter, 13 seems to be my unlucky number as it was also a counter example to another belief I had: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/544641/103591). PS. that was my question Bill!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the only counterexample is (113, 127, 13) as pointed out by Peter Košinár. Such a gap would be larger than the square root of $p_{n+1}$ and so it is easy to check that there are no examples with $p_n<4\cdot10^{18}$ using existing tables of maximal prime gaps. If there is another example it must be a gap at least 46 million times the length of the average gap of at its size.